# Плавная смена источника фото на jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, вёрстка

Есть примерно следующий код, реализующий смену картинки при наведении на определенный блок. При этом картинка меняется резко. Можно ли как-то сделать эту смену плавной?

```js
function change_src(){
    let i = 1;

    $("#change").mouseleave(function() {
      i++;
      $('#pic').attr('src', 'https://picsum.photos/id/' + i + '/200/300');
    })
}

change_src();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="change">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300" alt="" id="pic">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Это очень неправильный подход, так не получиться. При наведении вы говорите что б у Вас вместо одного src адреса подставился другой. Если картинка будет большого размера или её вообще по какой-то причине не будет, вы ничего не увидите.  Правильнее будет держать сразу все необходимые картинки, и по наведению курсора,допустим опускать opacity выше лежащей картинки к 0 (этот эффект можно контролировать)

Comment: У меня есть 5 абсолютно одинаковых, за исключением цвета, наборов картинок. При этом картинки приводятся в движение через transform. Менять их нужно по кругу. При этом их положение в момент замены должно совпадать. Картинка ТОЧНО есть и ее размер ТОЧНО совпадает с размером предыдущей картинки

Comment: да один черт, расположите одну над другой и меняйте прозрачность

Answer (score 0):

```js
let i = 1;

$("#change").mouseleave(function() {
  $('#pic-' + i).fadeOut(300, function(){ 
      $(this).remove();
  });
  i++;
  $('#change').prepend('<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/' + i + '/200/300" alt="" id="pic-' + i + '" class="slide">');
})
```

```css
.slide{position:absolute}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="change">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300" alt="" id="pic-1" class="slide">
</div>
```